# Topology of a multiple feedback filter with differential input

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, differential

While looking for a multiple feedback filter with differential inputs and single ended output I came across those two low-pass filter which are identical excepted for C2 capacitor.

Will the transfer function of those two design be equivalent? If not what will be the difference?

1. C2 to the ground

Proposed in application note AN48 by CRYSTAL

[image]

2. C2 combined

Found in a paper from TI : Using the infinite-gain, MFB filter topology in fully differential active filters

[image]

Comment: 1) always indicate where you found these designs. 2) *If not which one is best?* If "best" means least amount of capacitors then obviously the 2nd design is better. Never ask for "best" or "better" without saying what is important. Is a Ferrari "better" than a Ford station wagon? What if I want to transport a large Ikea cupboard? Then the Ferrari is useless.

Comment: I edited my question according to your remarks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfer functions are identical (at least as far as differential mode input is concerned), the and the second one has the nice feature that you ca treat it as a 'ground compensating' design in that the output of the filter is referenced to the R5/C3 junction.

To transform the first into the second you simply place the two C2s in the first version in series and remove the ground reference at the centre.

If your following stage is also balanced input then you can build something where 'ground' serves only to define common mode voltage, but where the signal path itself is insensitive to ground noise.

There is a possible slight trap in that for common mode noise, the first design attenuates due to the passive R1C2 pole, where the second one relies on the difference amp. This might matter in things like heavily noise shaped DSMs where there can be a lot of high frequency common mode present.